# Overflow:auto causing scrolling/scroll bars to show up in Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I have a container div (#columnsOne) set up at 920px + 38px padding + 2px border for a total of 960px wide.

(#columnsOne) uses CSS "overflow: auto;" to expand vertically and contain everything inside of it.

This works on all browsers to expand the div vertically, and also displays the horizonal width correctly on Firefox, Chrome, and IE7/8. However, on Safari, a horizontal scroll appears, and scrolls about 600px of blank space to the right.

At first I thought I might have the margin/padding set wrong, and that's why it might be expanding right, but there is no way I have 600px of extra space there.

Any thoughts as to why this might occur?

http://www.timetoplaymag.com/giveaway/daily/

Screen shots (new user, so I can't post on here): http://www.timetoplaymag.com/stacko/

**many edits trying to get the code in here, newbie, sorry**

```
 <div class="columnsOne">

        <div class="sectionLeft">

            image/name of giveaway are here

        </div>

        <div class="sectionRight">

          sign in form here

        </div>

    </div>


#columnsOne, .columnsOne {
clear: both;
width: 958px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
height: auto;
border: 1px solid #77787b;
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
padding: none;
overflow: auto;
}   


#columnsOne .sectionLeft, .columnsOne .sectionLeft {
float: left;
height: auto;
width: 590px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
overflow: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
padding-top: 19px;
padding-right: 19px;
padding-bottom: 19px;
padding-left: 19px;
}

#columnsOne .sectionRight, .columnsOne .sectionRight {
height: auto;
width: 270px
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
overflow: auto;
padding-top: 19px;
padding-right: 19px;
padding-bottom: 19px;
padding-left: 19px;
}
```

Comment: The Chrome and safari pics look similar

Comment: We need to see the big elements of your HTML, overflow:auto WILL add a scroll bar when the contents overflow the size of it's container.

Comment: They are the exact same, except there is a scroll bar in Safari, and not Chrome (or Firefox or IE for that matter). I know a scroll bar should be added if the contents overflow, but, the contents do not overflow, especially not 600px or so, which is how much extra space Safari is adding on that right side...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `overflow-x:hidden;` after overflow auto, and on safari at least that rule will be applied.

Comment: This is good, thank you.

I still don't really understand why it's showing up in Safari and no where else, but this seems like a good solution until I can learn that.

Comment: @Billy I can't +1 this enough. Thank Billy, your answer really helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure `overflow:auto;` is the correct solution to be using here - you may want to read up on floats and how they control document flow.

However, I do notice when the width property is disabled on `.sectionright`, the extra space disappears.

Comment: That did work, thank you. I will use that as a solution at this point, I just don't see why the original code it works in all browsers, except safari.

As for floats: In this instance, I want the background color of white to cover the entire background, I've read for hours on the subject and aside from putting a clearing div at the bottom of the (#belly), I haven't read any other ways to go about this. I'd love to read up more on it, do you have any sources in mind for good reading on the subject? 

**edit: not used to pressing "return" to submit the form, sorry!"