# overflow-y not working in safari inside a modal

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

Ok here is the html:

```
<div style="height: 200px; position: relative;"  id="filterOptionsContainer">
    <table id="filterOptionsTable" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    </table>
</div>
```

Basically, I am dynamically adding rows to the table and I would like the container to scroll the overflow. First I tried the obvious:

```
#filterOptionsContainer {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

and that works fine everywhere except for Safari on iOS mobile devices.

Since then I have spent hours trying every combination of styles I can think of and read about but I cannot get standard overflow scrolling. The closest I got was getting the scrollbar to show (it wasn't actually scrolling though).

All help is appreciated. It is hard for me to believe that it is not possible to scroll the contents of a div in a modal in Safari...

Comment: You can use two nested divs. The outer has 'overflow: auto' , the inner has 'overflow: hidden' with a set width to stop the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: @Bug can you expand on this. I am not understanding how to implement...

Comment: Ive expanded on this in my answer below

Comment: Your list doesnt scroll on my iPhone6 were as my answer below does so you may have set a css rule somewhere that needs to be removed, eg.. In you filterOptionsContainer class the line: 'overflow: hidden;' doesnt need to be there.

Comment: Did you had a look at this page: [Safari Scrollbars](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) perhaps it might help you

Comment: @Bug I have changed it to use your rules. It still does not scroll. Care to take a look?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I resolved this by switching to a multiselect (and hiding the scrollable div) on mobile devices (so no real solution). Thanks for all the help everyone.

Edit: I have finally figured this out. Basically what happened was that after I switched to using a multiselect, it too was acting weirdly in IOS devices when using Safari.

In examining further a colleague of mine noticed dojo touch events on both the scrollable div and on the multiselect (the template I am using uses dojo). I started looking around in the template's source to figure out why these events were being attached to all these elements and I noticed a dojo module called "dojo/touch". After removing this module from the project, the elements are working fine in Safari.

The take away is that 'dojo/touch' and IOS Safari are totally incompatible.

Answer (score 16):

Try applying this inline , or through a Jquery Script

```
 style="overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;"
```

or through a Jquery Script

```
$("#filterOptionsContainer").css({
    "overflow-y": "scroll",
    "-webkit-overflow-scrolling": "touch"
});
```

Comment: Adding styles with JS works, but directly through CSS doesn't. Also, mine is in modal, so I set/unset the style when the modal is shown/hidden.

Comment: Might also be worth noting that resizing the window makes the scrolling work (even with `overflow: auto`, but progmatically dispatching a resize event doesn't help

Answer (score 6):

I don't have any IOS product to verify this, but it seems like `overflow: auto` is a known Safari bug.

Try this:

```
#filterOptionsContainer {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. This does not help, there is still no scrollbar.

Comment: Getting same issue. Tried both overflow-y as 'scroll' and 'auto', tried -webkit-overflow-scrolling as touch. Not working.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this. It's working fine with Safari.

```
#filterOptionsContainer {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; this one make the scroll smoothly in iphone safari.

Answer (score 2):

If none of the solutions work you could try flex: 1 1;  This has cross-browser support.

Comment: My parent container is a Flex element, so applying this solution to my Flex child totally fixed my issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can set `overflow-y:hidden;` after overflow auto, and on safari at least that rule will be applied.
[Ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719752/overflowauto-causing-scrolling-scroll-bars-to-show-up-in-safari)

Comment: If you're copying someone's answer you really should reference to that answer, rather than portraying it as your own.

Comment: It might, but add a reference to it. Link it.

Answer (score 1):

Code for using two nested divs to show vertical scroll bar only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="div1">     
    <div class="div2">     
111111<br>
222222222222222222222<br>
3333333333333333333333333333333333<br>
44444444<br>
55555555555555555555555555555<br>
6666666666666666666666666666<br>
77777777777<br>
88888888888888888888888888<br>
99999999999999999999999<br>
0000000000000000000000000000000<br>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
bbbb<br>
cccccccccccccccc<br>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<style>

.div1{
    overflow:auto;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.div2{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does indeed produce a scrollable div but on not on Safari.

Comment: Tested OK on my iPhone6 and safari for win, sorry

Comment: I edited the OP with a link of the broken scrolling. Would appreciate your input. I really need to solve this.

Comment: I cant get the mobile version working on my server however try removing this line in your viewer-min.css file in the #filterOptionsContainer class 'overflow:hidden;' This will stop scrolling and may be your problem

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, it work fine for me

```
#filterOptionsContainer {
    overflow: auto; 
    overflow-y: auto; 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: This is not a sufficient solution for safari.

Comment: Hi dewwwald, 

That is the good feedback for me, but can you share with us more about the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Check Your Version of Safari Browser. And match with criteria given below :

1. Available in Safari 3.0 and later.
2. Available in iOS 1.0 and later.

if you're against the conditions then get upto following measures:

1. Apply ClearFix

   `.clearfix:after {visibility: hidden;}`

**Reason**: Setting overflow doesn't clear the float at the element

**OR**

2. Set Position of element relative at root/body level like this :

   `body { position:relative; overflow-x:hidden; }`

**Note**: Apply only one of them.

Thanks & cheers

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, overflow does not work on safari with `display: flex`
You must use `display: block`