# ionic scroll bar not working on iphone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, ionic-framework

Hi my scroll bar does not work on an iphone, I can not scroll through my images when i drag them on an android phone i can do it but on a iphone it just stays there with out moving. i tryed adding in this code `style="overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;"` which i got from [overflow-y not working in safari inside a modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469227/overflow-y-not-working-in-safari-inside-a-modal/35560173#35560173)

but it still does not scroll here is my code

***HTML:***

```
<div class="streaming scrolling" style="overflow-x: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;"><div><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/89/4a/af/894aaf28f0b9ebb42f5de80f21a250af.jpg" alt="" height="140" width="160"><p class="streamtitle">Title 1</p></div>
            <div><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/89/4a/af/894aaf28f0b9ebb42f5de80f21a250af.jpg" alt="" height="140" width="160"><p class="streamtitle">Title 1</p></div>
            <div><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/89/4a/af/894aaf28f0b9ebb42f5de80f21a250af.jpg" alt="" height="140" width="160"><p class="streamtitle">Title 1</p></div>
            <div><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/89/4a/af/894aaf28f0b9ebb42f5de80f21a250af.jpg" alt="" height="140" width="160"><p class="streamtitle">Title 1</p></div>
            <div><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/89/4a/af/894aaf28f0b9ebb42f5de80f21a250af.jpg" alt="" height="140" width="160"><p class="streamtitle">Title 1</p></div>
            <div><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/89/4a/af/894aaf28f0b9ebb42f5de80f21a250af.jpg" alt="" height="140" width="160"><p class="streamtitle">Title 1</p></div>
            <div><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/89/4a/af/894aaf28f0b9ebb42f5de80f21a250af.jpg" alt="" height="140" width="160"><p class="streamtitle">Title 1</p></div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.scrolling div{
  padding: 0px 5px;
  width: 40px;
  display: table;
}


.scrolling {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
```

Please Help me Thank You

Comment: Can anyone please help me?

Comment: can someone help me @Community